# Asp.Net Core Views - best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm developing an online shop website which will contain a default set of functionalities as products pages, product categories, commentaries, personal cart etc.
This is the first time I'm doing such project and during implementation of features I'm faced some difficulties with handling different exceptions in Views. Hence I would like to understand best practices of designing good code in Views which would be extendable in the future.

Let's say I have a Shop controller with Category action that displays list of products related to the category we are in. In corresponding category View I need to loop over product list and depending on user's role and authorization (admin, user, guest) hide some inactive products. The way I'm doing it now is something like this (code is simplified):

```
@model ProductList

@foreach (var i in Model) {
   @if (i.Product.Active || UserManager.IsInRole(User, "Admin")) {
   <div class="product">    
      @if (i.Data.Path == null) {
          <img src="placeholder.png">
      }
      else {
          <img src="@i.Data.Path">
      }   
   ...
   </div>
   }
}
```

While it looks intuitively clear, I realized that sooner or later this will become very messy once I add few more conditional branching. So my question: is there any other approach to handle such exceptions branching? I've heard about custom HtmlTagHelpers (which could make code more HTML looking while keeping some conditional logic behind), but it looks that it will take more time to explicitly write logic for each exception.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Best practices, I would argue using .Net's MVVM, is not a good choice.  In general your front end should not be coupled to your backend.  It might be better to just use WebApi instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views must not contain data logic, all your data logic must be in the backend, and for your case, put the logic where you do query for the products. e.g.:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var query = UserManger.IsInRole(User, "Admins") 
        ? _context.Set<Products>()
        : _context.Set<Products>().Where(x => x.IsActive == false);

    Products = await query.Skip(/*number*/).Take(/*quantity*/).ToListAsync();

    // ...
}
```

#### UPDATE

As mentioned in the comment, view logic can take place inside the view e.g.:

```html
@if(!Product.IsInStock)
{
    <span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, couldn't think about such approach before. Thank you! Just one question, what if I have conditions like (if model.InStock) which should show different html depending on variable? Should I leave it as is in View?

Comment: Yes, view logic can take place in view :) see updated answer.

Comment: @LazZiya The view logic can take place there, but in general you shouldn't put it there because it will make it a pain in the ass to refactor out the template logic

Comment: @johnny5 you are right, but it will not be a problem for simple cases as in the given sample. Anyhow Html helpers, partial views, view components and razor components are there to simplify more complex scenarios.

Comment: @LazZiya yeah, for a technology as a whole it makes development occur in a single language but you sacrifice a lot of server resources producing those views